# How can I embed a third-party web page using an embedded browser in a WinJS application?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

When developing Windows 8 apps with C# / XAML you can embed a third-party web page into an application using the [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) control.

What's the equivalent for WinJS? IFrame? HtmlControl?

My requirement is that I'm building a content reader application and I need to be able to render third-party web pages in-app without blowing up the WinJS security sand-box or without scraping out the relevant content from each third-party web page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the IFrame to open a third-party web page within your application using the html control `<iframe>`.

You also have to set the URIs you want to include/exclude in your application in your package.appxmanifest in the Content URIs tab.

Comment: That is not correct! You do not have to add the URIs to the `package.appxmanifest`. It is enough to add the `Internet (Client)`capability to the manifest. Else you will get a `resource not found` error.

Comment: this post date from Windows 8.0 RTM version back there you needed to add URI's in the manifest. I haven't dev with WinJS since it may have changed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

The answer is that you should use an iframe inside your WinJS application to load the content outside of the current security context of your application.

I just tested this locally and it appears it work.

Moreover, Microsoft has a couple of relevant examples in their Win8 dev center which show you how to do it.

**Win8 Dev Center**: [Integrating content and controls from web services sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Mashup-Sample-10689f5b) (shows you how to embed content from third-party services inside the various security contexts)

**Relevant MSDN forum thread**: [The Metro application does not allow JavaScript to use external network file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithhtml5/thread/f5a852c1-c757-40f2-bc41-8d6a190a233e)